# How to make an offline translator?

Tags: neural-network, translation, translate, apertium

**Problem: **

- The result must be a working translator - offline.

  We need http API (self-hosted) similar to Google Translate.

I found a few options:

- Install [Microsoft Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/translator/9wzdncrfj3pg?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) on Windows, download dictionaries, and somehow through http transfer requests for translation there
- [Apertium](https://www.apertium.org), this option is closer to reality, but it’s not clear how to set everything up ...
- [Apache Joshua](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JOSHUA/)
- [Promt](http://www.promt.com/corporate/developers/pts/), it is perfect but it is very expensive
- Install Android on PC, and there is already Google Translate, but again there will be a question of sending http requests

**Todo: **

- We need to translate whole sentences, not just individual words.
- Maybe there is some kind of command line utility. 
  Or maybe there is something for linux.

  Which of the above options is better to look for more information?

Comment: here is question on russian SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899930/Как-сделать-переводчик-оффлайн

Comment: Please note that asking for software/library recommendations is off topic here

Answer (score 5):

The five-minute solution is to do this on Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install apertium-apy      # http server for apertium
sudo apt install apertium-eng-spa  # install some language data
sudo systemctl enable apertium-apy # start http server on next boot
sudo systemctl start apertium-apy  # start http server right now too
```

You now have translation between English and Spanish that responds to http requests and answers in JSON:

```
curl 'http://localhost:2737/translate?langpair=spa|eng&q=Eres+la+leche'
```

You can see all the apt-installable Apertium language pairs with

```
apt-cache search apertium |grep 'pair$'
```

If you want more pairs in Apertium, you could try the adding the [nightly](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Install_Apertium_core_using_packaging#Debian-based) apt repo with unreleased data (or consider [Contributing](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Contributing) your own language data).

---

However, you tagged this neural-network – if you want NN's, or more language pairs than Apertium has, you could train a translator with [OpenNMT](http://opennmt.net/) and data from e.g. http://opus.nlpl.eu/ , but that will definitely take more than five minutes :-)